# Who are the sons of Pulastya that were born as Duryodhana's brothers?

Tags: mahabharata, avatars, rakshasa, kauravas

Rishi PUlastya had sons who were born as Duryodhana's brothers. Whhat are the names of the sons of Pulastya that were born as Duryodhana's brothers?

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm

> **They who had been the sons of Pulastya (the Rakshasas) were born on earth among men of Duryodhana's brothers**, that century of wicked individuals commencing with Duhasasana as their first. And, O bull among the Bharata princes, **Durmukha, Duhsaha, and others whose names I do not mention, who always supported Duryodhana (in all his schemes)**, **were, indeed, the sons of Pulastya.**